# How to replace NA elements of a dataframe with two other dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have one dataframe, called to_add:

```
 1999 2000 2001 2002
3   NA   NA   NA   NA
6   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

and 2 other dataframes, series_J6 and series_V2

```
 1999 2000 2001 2002
2   NA   NA   23   NA
5   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

```
 1999 2000 2001 2002
3   NA   NA   25   12
6   NA   NA   25   NA
```

I want Na values in to_add to be replaced with corresponding elements from series_J6 first, and then series_V2 (so that to_add[1,3] will be 23 and not 25).  Here's my code:

```
  to_add[1,] = ifelse(is.na(to_add[1,]), series_J6[1, ], to_add[1,])
  to_add[2,] = ifelse(is.na(to_add[2,]), series_J6[2, ], to_add[2,])
  to_add[1,] = ifelse(is.na(to_add[1,]), series_V2[1, ], to_add[1,])
  to_add[2,] = ifelse(is.na(to_add[2,]), series_V2[2, ], to_add[2,])
```

but it's clunky. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We place the datasets in a `list` and `coalesce`

```
library(tidyverse)
list(df1, df2, df3) %>%
     reduce(coalesce)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`1999` = c(NA, NA), `2000` = c(NA, NA), `2001` = c(NA, 
NA), `2002` = c(NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("3", 
"6"))

df2 <- structure(list(`1999` = c(NA, NA), `2000` = c(NA, NA), `2001` = c(23L, 
NA), `2002` = c(NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2", 
"5"))

df3 <- structure(list(`1999` = c(NA, NA), `2000` = c(NA, NA), `2001` = c(25L, 
25L), `2002` = c(12L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("3", 
"6"))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there an equivalent way to do this in base R?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R way. We can write a function that checks the `NA` indices in the dataframe to replace, and then replaces those indices with the corresponding ones from a replacement dataframe. This uses the nice ability for `data.frame` to take matrices as indexers.

```r
df1 <- structure(list(`1999` = c(NA, NA), `2000` = c(NA, NA), `2001` = c(NA, NA), `2002` = c(NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("3", "6"))
df2 <- structure(list(`1999` = c(NA, NA), `2000` = c(NA, NA), `2001` = c(23L, NA), `2002` = c(NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2", "5"))
df3 <- structure(list(`1999` = c(NA, NA), `2000` = c(NA, NA), `2001` = c(25L, 25L), `2002` = c(12L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("3", "6"))

replace_na_cells <- function(df, replace) {
  replace_idxs <- which(is.na(as.matrix(df)), arr.ind = TRUE)
  df[replace_idxs] <- replace[replace_idxs]
  df
}

Reduce(replace_na_cells, list(df1, df2, df3))
#>   1999 2000 2001 2002
#> 3   NA   NA   23   12
#> 6   NA   NA   25   NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>